# How to manipulate links in a javafx browser

Tags: java, netbeans, web, browser, javafx

```
        //process history
        final WebHistory history = webEngine.getHistory();

        history.getEntries().addListener(new 
            ListChangeListener<WebHistory.Entry>(){
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Change<? extends Entry> c) {
                    c.next();
                    for (Entry e : c.getRemoved()) {
                        comboBox.getItems().remove(e.getUrl());

                    }

                    for (Entry e : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        comboBox.getItems().add(e.getUrl());
                    }
                        System.out.println(webEngine.getLocation());
                    if(webEngine.getLocation().matches("http://www.google.co.in/")){}
                    else if(webEngine.getLocation().contains("http://in.yahoo.com/")){}
                    else{

          browser.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

          @Override
          public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {

                String[] manipulateurl= {
                                         "http://www.gmail.com",
                                         "http://www.flipkart.com"};
                String temp=address.getText();


               if (manipulatedindex>1)
                   manipulatedindex=0;

               temp=manipulateurl[manipulatedindex];
               System.out.println(manipulateurl[manipulatedindex]+"      "+temp);
               address.setText(temp);


                webEngine.load(temp);
                manipulatedindex++;

}

    });}



//                         webEngine.getLocation()
                }
        });

        //set the behavior for the history combobox               
        comboBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent ev) {
                int offset =
                        comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()
                        - history.getCurrentIndex();
                history.go(offset);
            }
        });



        // process page loading
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov,
                    State oldState, State newState) {
                    toolBar.getChildren().removeAll(showAll, hideAll);    
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            JSObject win = 
                                (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                            win.setMember("app", new JavaApp());
                            if (needForumButtons) {
                                toolBar.getChildren().addAll(showAll, hideAll);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        // load the home page  
        String x="http://www.google.com";
    webEngine.load(x);
        //add components

        getChildren().add(toolBar);


        getChildren().add(browser);
    }

    // JavaScript interface object
    private class JavaApp {

        public void exit() {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }

    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        double tbHeight = toolBar.prefHeight(w);
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h-tbHeight,0,HPos.CENTER,VPos.CENTER);
        layoutInArea(toolBar,0,h-tbHeight,w,tbHeight,0,HPos.CENTER,VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 600;
    }
}
```

This is my code. Can someone help me to manipulate links on the browser for example lets say that when i click on "Advertising Programs" in google.com it should go to  (propams.com) with the url where i have clicked

Thanks for helping me in advance.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulating" links? Does not clicking on a url lead you the destination? If you are seeing that your GUI freezes during this, it could be a commonly seen concurrency issue. If you want to parse links/change them then that's another interesting issue.
Please do read through basics of a good question on stack* sites.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? i'd like a quick sneak peek at the code snippet. My code seems to fail at history.go(offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you should first try to understand how history is displayed in the browser if you figure that out then i guess you just have to write a simple if else logic to manipulate links to wherever you want so first try to display history i guess that should do the trick

Comment: ok i tried that and i got the history but could you help me figure what logic should i use

Comment: just simply use if (gethistory){manipulate link} i hope u got it